# WT maximized with profile

Tags: windows-terminal

I am trying to launch the Windows Terminal maximized with a specific profile, however:

- `wt -M` opens the terminal maximized with the default profile
- `wt -p "{profile name}"` opens the terminal with the given profile
- `wt -M -p "{profile name}"` causes an error:
  "*The following argument was not expected: -M 
  Run with --help for more information.*"

What am I doing wrong?

Edit(18-08-20): Was confirmed as a bug on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/7318)
As a side note, if you need 2 tabs or splitscreen, this seems to work: `wt -p "profile 1" ; -M sptit-pane -p "profile 2"`

Edit(30-01-21): Was fixed with [this](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/commit/817df81f4893f5d618148ff3ec3b16ffc088a483) commit and relesed with **Windows Terminal v1.5.10271.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a bug, I didnt look into it further. If you don't mind opening maximized with an extra tab you can do:

`wt -p "{profile name}" ; -M`

Comment: Indeed it opened WT with the 2 tabs. So I tried: wt -p "{profile 1}" ; -M split-pane  -p "{profile 2}" for example wt -p "Command Prompt" -d D:/ ; -M split-pane -d D:/ -p "Windows PowerShell" and it worked, so I am guessing you are right and this is a bug! Should I open an Issue on Github?

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if you wanted a split pane but yeah the [command seperator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/----command-separator-) is great. I would search the exisiting wt issues on github as there are many and then if there is not an issue already logged (which there probably is), log it ;)

Comment: I had looked through the issues before posting here, but couldn't find anything relevant. Already created an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/7318), Thanks for your time 